# Change file from being flagged as a 'system file' back to 'normal' state on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a mp3 file which is flagged as a 'System File' according to Windows 7.

Is there a way to change this file back to a 'Normal' file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"System files" in Windows 7 are files tagged with the following two attributes:

- Archive
- System

"Hidden system files" in Windows 7 are files tagged with the following three attributes:

- Archive
- Hidden
- System

To reset "System files", simply run the following command:

```
attrib -A -S file.ext
```

To reset "Hidden System files", run the following:

```
attrib -A -H -S file.ext
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running "attrib -S filename" from a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If it's flagged as a system file, it might also be flagged as a hidden file, so open command prompt, then `cd C:\path\to\folder` and then `attrib -h -s song.mp3`. The minus sign means removing an attribute, 'h' stands for hidden, 's' stands for system. For adding an attribute, change -h to +h.

Answer (score 1):

To change all files in the folder put * instead of file name - this can save a lot of time.

```
attrib -A -H -S *
```

Comment: your suggestion is basically the accepted answer already.

Answer (score 0):

To clear "hidden" and "system" attributes recursively in a directory:

```
cd directory
attrib -S -H /S /D
```

Documentation:

```
>attrib /?

Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+O | -O] [+I | -I] [+X | -X] [+P | -P] [+U | -U]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D]] [/L]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  O   Offline attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
  X   No scrub file attribute.
  V   Integrity attribute.
  P   Pinned attribute.
  U   Unpinned attribute.
  B   SMR Blob attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
  /L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
      the target of the Symbolic Link
```